# DataTable data dynamic using django View

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-views, datatables

I m working on demo project to fetch the data form db using datatable on templates.
i m getting an error *****Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined*****

my code

.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#mytable").dataTable({
'bProcessing':true,
"bServerSide": true,
"sAjaxSource": "{% url 'all-user' %}"
});
```

});

html

```
<table id="mytable"  width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<thead></thead>
<tbody></tbody>
```

url

```
url(r'^all-user/$',UserListView.as_view(),name='all-user')
```

my issue is sAjaxSource is not hitting the url
pls help in solving this issue.

Comment: I'm not familiar with django, what does that url translate as?

Answer (score 0):

Is the javascript included in the Django template? If it is in a separate js file in your static directory, then it is not possible to use the url tag, and you should change it to

```
"sAjaxSource": "/all-user/"
```